# Ionic2 ngModel not updating value returned from function inside ngOnit()

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a text box on my page and I assign the value dynamically using ngModel.And in my component, I'm using ngOnint() to call a function that set the ngmodel value. When I run my app the value is not updating in the text box.

```
<ion-input #CurrentLocation readonly [(ngModel)]="location" type="text"> 
</ion-input>

component.ts
export{
    ngOnit(){  this.getGeo()}

    location:any;

    getGeo(){
        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
            resp.coords.latitude
            resp.coords.longitude
            this.reversecode( resp.coords.latitude,resp.coords.longitude);
        }).catch((error) => {
            alert('Error getting location'+JSON.stringify(error));
        });}

    reversecode(lat,lon){
        let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var geolat=new  google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);

        geocoder.geocode({ 'location': geolat }, (results, status) => {
            this.currentaddress=results[0].formatted_address;
            console.log("address",this.currentaddress)
            this.location=this.currentaddress;   
        });
    }
}
```

I am getting the value on the console but not displaying on the text field when page loads. But it is displaying once i click the input field.

Comment: Add some code in your question

Comment: Help me to resove this issue. @Faisal

Comment: That is not helpful at all ! Please add the code from you app where you have this problem.

Comment: //somefunction() that updates the ngModel ..This is exactly what we need to solve the problem

Comment: added code.check out.

Comment: @Faisal check the code and help

Comment: @VikhyathMaiya check the code and help

Answer (score 1):

It should look something like this:

```
<!-- TYPESCRIPT -->
location = '';
ngOnInit() {
    this.location = 'HELLO, this value should show up in the ion-textarea';
}


<!-- HTML -->
<ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="location"></ion-textarea>
```

Comment: Whats the error? "Its not working" does nothing for either of us

Comment: I am getting (this.location) value on the console but not displaying on the text field when page loads. But it is displaying once i click the input field.